# Multi Processing for loop

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I am trying to create a script that clones repositories and then removes write access from the local repos. I have a list that stores a repo object and I iterate over this list to clone and lock the repo.

I tried using `multiprocessing` to speed up this task but it seems to have actually slowed it down...

```
def install():
    os.chdir(ROOT_DIR)
    if os.path.isdir("./repos"):
        for repo in getRepos():
            os.chdir(ROOT_DIR)
            #Process(target=repo.clone()).start()
            #Process(target=lock, args=(repo,)).start()
            repo.clone()
            lock(repo)
    else:
        os.mkdir("./repos")
        install()
```

The two commented lines are the subproccesses that I tried to create. Am I using this wrong?

With subprocessing my average execution time was: 5.8 seconds
Without subprocessing my average execution time was: 4.5 seconds.

Comment: You're creating processes at each loop iteration, each process will work on one repo only. You want to ideally delegate a group to work on a chunk of them. The answer below solves that for you but does not explain what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def processRepo(repo):
    repo.clone()
    lock(repo)


def install():
    os.chdir(ROOT_DIR)
    if os.path.isdir("./repos"):
        pool = Pool()
        pool.map(processRepo, getRepos())
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    else:
        os.mkdir("./repos")
        install()
```

Comment: This is good and probably works. But an explanation of what you're doing would certainly help OP and future readers. Also, include `from multiprocessing import Pool`

Comment: Perfect! This brought execution to around 3.4 seconds, why is that I don't have to pass a repo argument to processRepo?

Comment: @APorter1031: Because [`pool.map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map).